# Allow only one hypen between alphanumeric and alphacharacters

Tags: objective-c, regex

A string can start with either alphachar(small/capital) or number and there should be only one hypen (-) then alpha characters(small/capital). I need something like below

```
Input string ==> "Ask123ques321tion-queStioNs"
NSString * regex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z]-{1}[A-Za-z]"
```

I tried above regex, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
^[A-Z0-9a-z]+-{1}[A-Za-z]+$
```

or may be

```
[A-Z0-9a-z]+-{1}[A-Za-z]+
```

your regex is only checking for three characters, thats why it doesnt work